# Backend JavaScript Server not working with Express - Neither in browser nor terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, server, backend

First time posting on StackOverflower. Pretty sure the question will be very poorly structured as I am also new to programming. However, if I can add more details please let me know. Appreciate you reading!

The problem is such, I am following a Udemy course where the instructor is using Linux, and I myself am using windows terminal. We are both using visual studio code text editor for the code, and we have:

- created a directory in VSC.
- within this directory we have created a package.json file by the command 'npm init -y'.
- we have installed express there by 'npm install express'.
- Express is there with its contents, and a new file called package-lock.json has appeared.
- we created a new file 'server.js' and copied the following code there to create a backend server;

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
console.log(`Server running on port 3000`)
})

[SAD EMOJI] - The problem is that when I check the browser 'localhost:3000' there is no feedback, and when I run the command in windows cmd or terminal or powershell 'node server.js' there is no server.

So far I have tried the following resolutions:

- Change port number.
- Headbutt wall 7 times.

Both have resulted in futile success, and neither have any of the other miscellaneous methods. Please, if anybody has experienced this issue, I would be elated if you share the golden secrets with me!

Many blessings,

Omer

I tried changing the port number, thinking it might be that my computer is using the current port number. Didn't work. Tried reinstalling node,js thinking I may have botched it up somewhere. Didn't work. Tried editing variable paths. Didn't work. Tried contacting discord course community. Didn't work.. yet. Tried contacting course provider. Didn't work... yet. Tried using windows linux subsystem. Didn't work.

Comment: What do you expect to see when you visit localhost:3000?

Comment: You have no route so it is normal to see nothing in the browser. But you should see `Server running on port 3000` in the console where you typed `node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to access `localhost:3000` on the browser, it sends a  `GET` request to the express server on the default route which is `'/'`.

you need to create a route in your server to access it from the browser.

Example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port 3000`);
});
```

You will see this output on browser whenever you will access `localhost:3000`
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ4ZV.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
do it like me 

 const express = require('express');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const app = express();
 const port = 5500;

 app.use(cors()); // enable CORS
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

  res.status(400).json('okey');
 });


  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```